# How to create a PL/SQL variable of %ROWTYPE for multiple db_links

Tags: oracle, plsql

PL/SQL does not like this line (see the procedure below):
`my_table_rec my_data_table@g_db_link%ROWTYPE;`
How do I create a common %ROWTYPE variable?
my_data_table exists in all the source databases; and the destination
database also has the exact table.

I have a procedure in a package like this....

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY concatenator_pkg
AS

--This procedure inserts records to one destination table in destination

--database from same name tables existing in multiple remote databases.

PROCEDURE my_proc (g_db_link VARCHAR2) IS

 l_my_query (5000) := 'SELECT * FROM my_data_table@'||g_db_link;

 get_my_data_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

 **my_table_rec my_data_table@g_db_link%ROWTYPE;**  -- PL/SQL errors here

--Says PLS-00201: identifier my_data_table@g_db_link must be declared

--     PLS-00352: Unable to access another database g_db_link

BEGIN

  OPEN get_my_data_cursor FOR l_my_query;

  LOOP
  BEGIN
    FETCH get_my_data_cursor INTO my_table_rec;

    EXIT WHEN get_my_data_cursor%notfound;
    --do my work with the data
  END LOOP;
END my_proc;

END concatenator_pkg;
```

And then I call the above procedure from an execution block (in a separate) file like this

```sql
DECLARE

  l_db_link VARCHAR(50);

BEGIN

  --Note I am showing just the lines needed for this question.

  l_db_link := 'mv_dev_db_01';
  concatenator_pkg.my_proc(l_db_link);

  l_db_link := 'mv_dev_db_02';
  concatenator_pkg.my_proc(l_db_link);

  l_db_link := 'mv_dev_db_03';
  concatenator_pkg.my_proc(l_db_link);

END;
```

Comment: If all your remote and local databases have the same table and definition, why not just define it with the local table's `%ROWTYPE`?

Comment: For this `my_table_rec my_data_table@g_db_link%ROWTYPE;` to work `g_db_link` has to be an actual dblink, not varchar2 containing name of dblink.

Comment: Alex, yes I did that too. Then no compilation errors. But during execution, it stops at EXIT WHEN get_my_data_cursor%notfound; as if no data.

Comment: That's not because of the rowtype declaration; that means it's run out of data. If you have some real work where you currently have a 'do my work' comment (or even just debugs - using `dbms_output`, and your client configured to show that output), and you can see that it never reaches that, then the query is returning no data.

Comment: Here is how I debugged it..... 1. I left the query as is where you can see I concatenate the db_link comnig from the caller. I can prove the query works,  I tested just with the first incoming db_link, buy hardcoding it's ROWTYPE  to mv_dev_db_01's ROWTYPE like this: my_table_rec my_data_table@mv_dev_db_0%ROWTYPE; and I see the destination table gets filled. But then moment I change the ROWTYPE to the Destination table row type like this my_table_rec my_data_table%ROWTYPE; I see no data getting into the destination table.

Comment: Also I put DMBS_OUPUT statements before and after EXIT WHEN get_my_data_cursor%notfound; statement and I see it does not reach the DBMS_OUTPUT after the EXIT WHEN when I have the FETCH ROWTYPE as Destination table row type

Comment: If the tables are the same then that should work. Maybe it's throwing an error and you've suppressed it - does you real procedure have a `when others` exception handler perhaps? Or your caller? Can you add a debug to check it gets past the `end loop`?

Comment: Yes I do have the EXCEPTION BLOCK in the procedure and I have a error table where I write the error and it says  : ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -

Comment: Right, then the table definitions are not the same. If they are similar with same column names and data types but have columns in a different order then you could replace `select *` with `select col1, col2, ...` in the order the columns appear in your local table. Otherwise you're probably going to have to make the whole thing dynamic, which will be painful.

Comment: Yes you are right. Our development team have been told they are the same table structure. Appears not. Ill try the select with col names. When the columns set is large it is a pain to define each column while the select statement is large. Thank you for your time.

Comment: As your cursor query is dynamic anyway you could query `user_tab_cols` and listagg the column names together, (a) to save typing them but also (b) in case they change in the future.

Comment: Yes, I did that it works now. Problem is I have n number tabels :-) . So I have to do this in each procedure that does the copy per table. Thank you so much.